# How to create Child Category page from scratch at wordpress?

Tags: categories

As we know we can build a parent category page directly as by file name category-category_name.php. Is there any such process to create a page for child category page. That I have 
"Continent" - Parent Category and
"Country" - Child Category - I want to create a page of Country with scratch.

Comment: You mean, [`category-country.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/taxonomy-templates/#category)?

Comment: from category-country.php we can only create parent category page, i want child or sub category page

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly you mean by "child category page"? What is it for? What are you trying to do?

Comment: You can create a category archive template for every category, no matter what level. So you could have `category-continent.php` plus `category-country.php` plus `category-city.php` and so forth.

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand what you're asking but here's my guess...

Say you have hierarchical taxonomy (e.g. category) with the following term tree:

- News (ID: 1)

  - World (ID: 2)

    - Africa (ID: 5)
    - Asia (ID: 6)
    - Europe (ID: 7)
  - Business (ID: 3)
  - Science (ID: 4)

Now you visit `/category/news/world/africa/` WordPress will look for the following templates: `category-africa.php` or `category-5.php` but neither of those exist so WordPress falls back to `category.php` or `archive.php`.

If you're asking "Can WordPress work up the tree to the first existing template?" then no, it cannot. But you can implement this functionality with the following...

```php
/**
 * Recurisively check if a term or term parent has a specific template
 *
 * @param   WP_Term $term
 * @return  ?string
 */
function parent_term_template( WP_Term $term ) {

    /**
     * Find template by pattern: taxonomy_name-term_slug.php || taxonomy_name-term_id.php
     *
     * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/
     * @var ?string
     */
    $template = locate_template( "{$term->taxonomy}-{$term->slug}.php" ) ?: locate_template( "{$term->taxonomy}-{$term->term_id}.php" );

    /**
     * If template exists, return it
     */
    if ( $template ) {
        return $template;
    }

    /**
     * Else, check if parent template exists
     */
    else if ( !empty( $term->parent ) ) {
        return parent_term_template( get_term_by( 'id', $term->parent, $term->taxonomy ) );
    }

    /**
     * No template
     */
    return null;
}

/**
 * Filter the path of the current template before including it
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/
 */
add_filter( 'template_include', function( string $template ) {

    /**
     * Apply to all taxonomies
     */
    if ( is_category() || is_tag() || is_tax() ) {

        /**
         * Get term specific template location
         *
         * @var string
         */
        $found = parent_term_template( get_queried_object() );

        /**
         * If template exists, return it
         */
        if ( $found ) {
            return $found;
        }
    }

    return $template;

} );
```

This will check if the current view is either a category, tag or custom taxonomy archive page. If so, it takes the queried term and passes it to a recursive function that looks for a matching template up the tree of parents until one is found.

For example, if we're viewing `/category/news/world/africa/` and there is no `category-africa.php` template, this code will look for the direct parent template. In this case: `category-world.php` and if that doesn't exist it will move to `category-news.php` and finally if that doesn't exist, it will fall back to the default.

Still I have no idea if this answers your question but it might help somebody!